# Google TV Addon Using Live TV on Application

Tags: android, google-tv

Hi I'm an android developer, and just this week the new Google Tv Addon was released, so I started looking into it.

I found the Documentation horrible, I couldn't find any example, as a matter of fact the only code I found was a query for the Channel Listing ContentProvider.

So first, if some of you have already started developing for Google TV, could you share any valuable Examples or Info so we could all benefit

Second, I'm particularly interested on using something like Picture in Picture (PiP), to have my application maximized and Live TV on a small floating window; or having an app widget hovering or to the side of the Live TV app, does anyone know how to do any of these??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live TV has not been added yet as a part of the SDK.  They're still working on it.  You can change channels and find out which channel a viewer is on, but that's about it.  Live TV, PiP, etc are not available in the SDK yet.  You cannot overlay elements on top of the Live TV screen.

Comment: I hope they open the APIs soon